# Error when trying to save EF6 Model (Diagram)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm getting an error when I try to save my EF6 Model in Visual Studio.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Running transformation: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating2E969E7BB7507C0E92F45D70D6AE734916F1C3683B5A0611CF49C10204F34C69B4F2034763B4DA31B0F0721B51B303513DC99B843477A989AB522BF93554EA49.GeneratedTextTransformation.TypeMapper.VerifyCaseInsensitiveTypeUniqueness(IEnumerable`1 types, String sourceFile)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating2E969E7BB7507C0E92F45D70D6AE734916F1C3683B5A0611CF49C10204F34C69B4F2034763B4DA31B0F0721B51B303513DC99B843477A989AB522BF93554EA49.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() NT-LLB.AzureSqlDb   C:\Users\lars.hermansen\source\repos\NT-AZURE\NT-LLB.AzureSqlDb\AzureSqlModel.tt    1
```

I have tried searching for a while without finding any usefull info on the error. This error stops the updating and creation of auto-generated model files. for now I have manually added changes when I add or change tables, but I would really like to get rid of this problem and get the intended functionality back.

Comment: Why is there a 1 after the filename AzureSqlModel.tt?

Comment: It is a reference to line 1 in AzureSqlModel.tt
This is line 1 in AzureSqlModel.tt: 
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true"#>

Comment: I assume it was the array index.  Error says : Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, I'm still not sure where the problem is though.